# How can I disable a arrow button at the last slide of a carousel

Tags: sapui5

->Am the new learner of SAPUI5,am trying image popup with carousel,Now How can I disable a arrow button at the last slide of a carousel(No limit of images)?Thank you..

Comment: What did you try so far? Coding?

Comment: Please edit to add significantly more detail, as @matbtt said.  Your question should include a clear description of your problem and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sap.m.Carousel, there is a property ***loop*** which indicates if there will be a loop in the images of the Carousel.

***Defines whether the carousel should loop, i.e show the first page after the last page is reached and vice versa.***

Link:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Carousel/properties

Answer (score 0):

If you set the "loop" property of Carousel control to false, you will not see arrow icons at the beginning to left and at the end of the image set to the right.

Here is a carousel with loop set to true to display arrows always

```
<Carousel id="mockupCarousel" loop="true" items="{ProjectMockups}">
```

And this will hide arrows for the first slide and for the last slide image

```
<Carousel id="mockupCarousel" loop="false" items="{ProjectMockups}">
```